# Fastest way to bin an image along non-consecutive dimension

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

I have an image which is 700x2000 uint8. Now I want to bin, that is to calculate the sum over every 4 rows, which are not consecutive in memory.

Right now I am allocating a new array for this sum of the line and add every line to it.

```
float* binnedLine = new float[lineSize];
char* binnedLineInt = new char[lineSize];

for (int j = 0; j < nlines; j++) 
{
    if (j % binsize == 0) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lineSize; i++) 
        {
            binnedLine[i] = (static_cast<float> (static_cast<char>(data[j*lineSize + i]))) / binsize;
            binnedLineInt[i] = static_cast<char>(binnedLine[i]);
        };
    }
    else 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lineSize; i++) 
        {
            binnedLine[i] += (static_cast<float> (static_cast<char>(data[j*lineSize + i]))) / binsize;
            binnedLineInt[i] = static_cast<char>(binnedLine[i]);
        };
    }

    ...
}
```

However the performance is not really sufficient for my purposes (it takes 3ms per frame). Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: I'd profile it first to see which operations are the most costly, and optimize those. Are you running an optimized build?

Comment: Why don't you use a single array (use only `binnedLineInt` i.e. compute the floats and cast to int)?. Having two separate arrays is not very cache friendly and could affect performance. Also, this code can certainly be parallelized (either via multithreading or  `SIMD`  or both)

Comment: Thanks, I did not, the optimized build brings it down to 0.8 ms per frame. This might be enough, but I will try to profile the code. I still leave the question, since there might still be a better way to implement it.

Comment: Thanks, I don't use a single array, because I thought looping through the image according to how it is laid out in memory is faster. Therefore the 4 values to be averaged are not availble at the same time, and cannot be cast to an int after averaging. That's why I write them into a float array one after the other.

Comment: @MHO, It's still possible to do away with that second array, basically you'll end up with `binnedLineInt[i] += static_cast<char>(currFloatVal);` (the results will be slightly different due to rounding though)

Comment: @MHO: Your assumption about memory access is slightly flawed if you are working on a system with at least minimal data cache. Reading through 4 arrays in parallel isn't really going to hurt. In fact, if that 4 is a constant, the compiler may spot it and unroll the loop. The resulting memory fetches will run in parallel on superscalar processors (even ARM is, nowadays). However, writing to a float _array_ hurts caches. Every write goes to a unique address, and the cache liekly needs to read a whole line for a read-modify-write. A single float can stay in a register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting float values to char 4 times, but only keeping the last conversion. At the same time, we'll remove the `if` and the `%`, and also avoid superfluous divisions. Try this:

```
float* binnedLine = new float[lineSize];
char* binnedLineInt = new char[lineSize];

for (int j = 0; j < nlines; j += binsize) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lineSize; ++i) 
    {
        binnedLine[i] = static_cast<float>(data[j*lineSize + i]);
    };
    for (int k = 1; k < binsize; ++k)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lineSize; ++i) 
        {
            binnedLine[i] += static_cast<float>(data[(j+k)*lineSize + i]);
        };
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < lineSize; ++i) 
    {
        binnedLineInt[i] = static_cast<char>(binnedLine[i] / binsize);
    }
    ...
}
```

But as [@MSalters said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571960/fastest-way-to-bin-an-image-along-non-consecutive-dimension#comment95951068_54571960), you're likely better off accessing the four lines at once, as this avoids holding and writing to an additional float buffer:

```
char* binnedLineInt = new char[lineSize];

for (int j = 0; j < nlines; j += binsize) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lineSize; ++i) 
    {
        float sum = static_cast<float>(data[j*lineSize + i]);
        for (int k = 1; k < binsize; ++k)
        {
            sum += static_cast<float>(data[(j+k)*lineSize + i]);
        }
        binnedLineInt[i] = static_cast<char>(sum / binsize);
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, shorter code is easier to get right and easier to maintain.